VS Code child_process exec on Windows 11
All of a sudden all processes spawned by child_process.exec are executed in a visible terminal.
E.g. C# DevKit runs 'dotnet --info' and tries to parse the output. This fails since the process stdin/stdout redirect doesn't work in the visible terminal.
This is also true for the Redhat Xml extension.
My conclusion is that they both use the child_process module.
According to the documentation of child_process.exec one can pass windowsHide: true. But doesn't seem to be used by the extension, and it used to work.
Any ideas anyone?
I've tried downgrading both extensions and VS Code. The problem still persists.
A colleague also started to have the same problems today, but we don't understand why.
Is there a global setting for the child_process lib?

This was due to company roll out of Microsoft EPM.
learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/protect/epm-overview
Problem solved by uninstalling EPM
